# How do you show HTML5 video's poster on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, html5-video

My HTML5 video syntax is nearly the same as [this guy](http://www.kaltura.org/apis/html5lib/kplayer-examples/Player_Themable.html):

```
<video height="270" width="480"
    src="media/bbb.ogv" 
    poster="media/bbb.jpg" 
    durationHint="0:4:44">
</video>
```

On iPhone (iOS 5.0) and desktop Firefox, I can see the poster:

[image]

But on iPad (iOS 5.0.1) it does not appear. I recall that it used to work on iPads with iOS less than 5.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute URL for the poster image?

Comment: I managed to somehow crash my Safari on iPad. When I rebooted, I checked all the HTML5 example websites and the thumbnails miraculously started working. I want to know if anyone else can reproduce the problem of the black thumbnail on iPad.

Comment: I have tested the same bit of code in ipad with iOS 5.0 and the poster image is coming

Comment: Which HTML5 player you are using. I tried the same code with mediaelement player with latest mediaelement.js file and it worked for me. Your relative url path might not be correct. Check the url once again.

Comment: I am using plain `<video>`. I am not using a library.

Comment: I had the same issue with a poster image. Restarted the iPhone which seemed to solve the problem. Not sure how to reproduce.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the same code using absolute instead of relative paths:

```
<video height="270" width="480"
    src="http://cdn.kaltura.org/apis/html5lib/kplayer-examples/media/bbb_trailer_iphone.m4v" 
    poster="http://cdn.kaltura.org/apis/html5lib/kplayer-examples/media/bbb480.jpg" 
    durationHint="00:04:44">
</video>
```

If that doesn't work, their CDN might be blocking external referrers so try to save the files to your own local server and use absolute paths to them.

NOTE: you don't have to use absolute paths but it definitely helps when troubleshooting.

Another solution if that fails is to use an absolute-positioned image overlay that when clicked, uses JavaScript to activate the  tag below; but this is an older hack and shouldn't be required for iOS 5+.

iOS 3 definitely has a known problem with the poster attribute on video tags:
http://videojs.com/2010/09/ipad-iphone-video-poster-fix-bonus-javascript-placement-fix/

Comment: good call, I had the exact same problem and it was bugging me for ages. Moved the poster images into a directory without password protection, and the iPad could then read the images. (didn't need to change my relative paths into absolute paths btw). Thanks bcmoney!

Comment: Good point. I had problems in a password protected staging environment too.

Comment: Same issue here : poster image does not show if I load it from my own staging env server, but it does if I load it from another production server. I tried to use absolute path and to remove the password protection but that did not help. There should be something else ... perhaps this request response time ?